# How to get the value of the selected item from listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to retrieve all the data of the selected row from `listview`.

this is what I have tried so far.....

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object listItem = listview.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    }
});
```

now i don't know, how to get the elements from the `Object`.

Comment: can you show your adapter code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object listItem = (Object)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```

Usually the `Object` depends on what type of data are you sending into your `adapter`.